# Regex expression help java

Tags: java, regex, expression

I need help with this regex expression to seperate a `String="55555 <italic>bold-italic</italic>"` into `m.group[0]="55555" m.group[1]="italic" and m.group[2]="bold-italic`. Currently this expression `<(.*)>(.*)</\\1>` seperates the `italic` and `bold-italic`, but I am having trouble adding the part for the number.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use : `(\d+)\s*(<\w+>)(.*)<\/\w+>`

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/lA5bZ1/2)

Java code :

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    String pattern = "(\\d+)\\s*(<\\w+>)(.*)<\\/\\w+>";
    String input = "55555 <italic>bold-italic</italic>";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    if ( m.find())
    {
        System.out.println("First group : " + m.group(1));
        System.out.println("Second group : " + m.group(2));
        System.out.println("Third group : " + m.group(3));
    }
}
```

Output :

```
First group : 55555
Second group : <italic>
Third group : bold-italic
```

Comment: What if u want to use another word instead of "italic"?

Comment: I updated the regex, it should treat other words alike.

Answer (score 0):

When having to deal with regex, I like to use https://regex101.com/ to try different possibilities.
It is technically not made for Java but works very well nonetheless (sometimes you'll have to insert/delete escape characters to make it work).

For your example, the regex on m.group[0]="55555" should be something like ([1-9]*), depending on what values you want to allow exactly and whether that group should have a length restriction.